# I am trying to configure and setup and old rails project (2.3.8) in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-2, ruby-1.8.7

I am trying to setup rails 2.3.8 project in ubuntu 20.04
Ruby version is 1.8.7

I have installed ruby and and rails of these version successfully.
But when i try to run server using command script/server
I am getting this error

```
bundled_gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:7:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- rails/version (LoadError)
```

Also when I run `rake gems:install`, I get the same error.

Also I have commented gem file and then tried it but facing the issue still. I want to run the server.

Comment: Are you prefixing your commands with `bundle`?

Comment:  `bundle exec rails server`, and `bundle exec rake gems:install`